# Why laravel route point to myapp/public?

Tags: laravel, apache, digital-ocean

I have a laravel project which routes to the public folder when routing laravel blade view but works fine when routing through vue.js router eg
this is my subdomain https://omis.ezytrade.africa/ but when I route login page it opens another link with public in URL https://omis.ezytrade.africa/omis/public/Login

Comment: What is your Nginx server configuration? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I am using apache servers

Comment: No problem, you can share the configuration.